# Tableau display all IDs in case of user types asterisk in parameter filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau dashboard containing ID and other columns as dimension in crosstab report. It has one parameter named as filter which accepts comma separated values, it has been handled using below calculated field = "True"

Parameter: [Order ID - List]

```
CONTAINS("," + [Order ID - List] + ",", "," + STR([Order Id]) + ",")
```

problem is when user put "*" in the parameter filter it should display all the IDs in cross tab report. Please help me how to implement this using calculated field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check to see if `*` is provided and allow it to evaluate to TRUE, like so:

```
[Order ID - List] = "*" OR
CONTAINS("," + [Order ID - List] + ",", "," + STR([Order Id]) + ",")
```